# Is really there exists any kind constant that can explain expanding universe and increasing time?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime

I know far galaxies moving out from us I.e universe expanding I.e increasing space.There also time always growing up.From four dimensional analysis space time has covariance. I want to know is there exists any kind constant which is just ratio of total space and total time and which always remaining constant?

Comment: There’s dark energy, which according to current models is a type of energy density intrinsic to space that when the universe expands, stays the same. This is weird to think about because if the universe is expanding, you’d expect any ordinary energy density to be more spread out over time, but dark energy keeps the same density. That’s one of the reasons why it’s so mysterious. I don’t know about any constant that explains the arrow of time, but dark energy does explain the accelerated expansion.

Comment: Is this anyhow possible that actually time also accelerated with respect to something?@Thatpotatoisaspy

Comment: I know quantum mechanically time is a kind of parameter.

Comment: With respect to something? Do you mean like time dilation? I’m not entirely sure what it means for time to accelerate, but time dilation is a real thing, it can be dilated from gravity or from reaching relativistic velocities. The expansion of the universe has nothing to do with that, though. It’s caused by the mass-energy density of the universe. You can find this from General Relativity and the friedmann equations. Dark energy was inserted to explain the accelerating expansion, and other things like inflationary theory have been needed to explain things.

Comment: Well if you’re looking to unify the quantum theory notion of time with the general relativistic one, i can’t really give you an answer because of this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_time

Comment: You said that time dilation is not help to explain expanding universe.But time dilation may be related to interval of time.I try to understand is there any kind relation between total time(the time interval from beginning i.e Bigbang to now) and the volume of current universe.

Comment: Well, of course there is a relation between the time elapsed from the big bang to now and the “size” (or scale) of the universe, because the more time elapses the more it expands. The age of the universe you’ll commonly hear (about 13.7 billion years) is calculated for an observer in a co-moving frame of reference, but in principle the age observed can be different for another frame. But that’s just standard relativity. Perhaps i am misunderstanding your question, but i’m not sure how much the role of time would influence the expansion beyond that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99524/discussion-between-baponkar-and-thatpotatoisaspy).

Comment: The ratio between expanding space and time is called the scale factor. You can find its formula and chart in my earlier answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428231/what-happens-if-you-travel-through-space-at-the-same-rate-that-space-expands/428253#428253