# Using Hubble parameter to compare sizes now and then

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, space-expansion

What if the Hubble parameter is constant both in time and space.
How would the scale factor look like?
For $H_0=70~kms^{-1}Mpc^{-1}$, how much smaller would the universe be 14 billion years ago?

I'm trying to use $H(t) = \dot a/a$, from which I can get a differential equation, solving for a(t) yields:$$a(t) = a(0)e^{H_0t}$$
(where we can use $H_0$ instead of $H(t)$ since it is constant)
$$\\$$
But, plugging in $H_0 = 70~kms^{-1}Mpc^{-1}$:$$H_0t=70~kms^{-1}Mpc^{-1}*\frac{1}{3.09\times10^{19}}~Mpc~km^{-1}*(3600*24*365.25)sy^{-1}*14\times10^9y$$
$$\\$$
this results in $H_0t\approx 1$ and thus $a(14Gy)=a(0)e^1\approx 2.72a(0)\tag{1}$,

Since $V\propto a(t)^3R^3$, assuming a spherical universe, the universe would then be about $2.72^3 \approx 20$ times smaller in volume 14 billion years ago.

This, however seems like a really small number so I tried to adjust the Hubble parameter using Friedmann's equations, where:$$H^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{c^2}\rho(t)-\frac{kc^2}{R_o^2a(t)^2}+\frac{\Lambda}{3}$$

A universe with a constant Hubble parameter is driven entirely by the cosmological constant and the matter density is effectively zero. If we take for example a flat universe, then the Friedmann equation reduces to$$H^2 = \frac{\Lambda}{3}$$

So that the scale factor would now be$$a(t) = a(0)e^{\sqrt\frac{\Lambda}{3}t}$$

Now I'm thinking this could be something, so I look up the current value of the cosmological constant $\Lambda\simeq 10^{-35}~s^{-2}$, but plugging this in at time $t=14~Gy$ leads to$$\sqrt{\frac{\Lambda}{3}}~t=\sqrt\frac{10^{-35}~s^{-2}}{3}*(14\times10^9*365.25*24*3600)~s\approx 0.81$$

but now$a(14Gy)=a(0)e^{0.81}\approx2.24a(0)\tag{2}$

Which is even smaller than what I got in $(1)$ Because the cosmological constant is so small, the Friedmann equations actually didn't change much, but surely this universe must have gotten a lot bigger than that in 14 billion years?

Are there other ways I can approach this? We haven't been given a lot to work with in the course for this exercise and have barely scratched the surface on the Freidmann equations. I'm actually skipping ahead in the curriculum by using $\Lambda$. I have no idea how to solve this within the confines of the current chapter

Comment: See if this helps: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428231/what-happens-if-you-travel-through-space-at-the-same-rate-that-space-expands/428253#428253